# SSRS Expression To Return Last Day Number of Month When Only Have Month Number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Afternoon

What I need sounds quite simple but I need some assistance in doing it please.

I have a month number as a parameter for a report. I need to return the last day number of that month using an expression within SSRS.

So for example, 9 will return 30, 12 will return 31 and 2 will return 28 or 29 depending on leap years.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Get the day before the first day of the next month.

Comment: I dont have the next month, I only have the number of the month specified as a parameter. So the user will enter 9 if they want to see Septembers results, which they can run at any time of the year, so using GETDATE(), NOW(), TODAY() or whatever is not applicable.

Comment: The next month is current month (month parameter value) + 1, unless it's December.

Comment: OK, so how would you go about coding that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a second parameter that's hidden and returns the date used in your query.  Then set the default value of this hidden parameter to the following expression:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Parameters!MonthNumber.Value, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

This assumes your month number parameter that the user enters will always be for the current year.

Answer (score 0):

The [DateSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function is perfect for these kind of operations.

> If Day is 0, the result is the last day of the previous month.

To get the day number of the previous month

```
=Day(DateSerial(Year(Now), Parameters!MonthNumber.Value, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
=FORMAT(DateSerial((Parameters!Year.Value), Parameters!Month.Value, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1),"dd.MM.yyyy")
```